# Visual basic writing smallest number program

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to visual basic and I'm trying to write a program to determine the smallest number out of three. Every time I run the program it doesn't pull up the message box.  This is what I have so far:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim TextBox1 As Integer
    Dim TextBox2 As Integer
    Dim TextBox3 As Integer

    TextBox1 = Val(TextBox1)
    TextBox2 = Val(TextBox2)
    TextBox3 = Val(TextBox3)

    If TextBox1 < TextBox2 And TextBox1 < TextBox3 Then
        MessageBox.Show(TextBox1)


    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict for all your projects. It will point out many errors for you.

Comment: Your button event has no idea that your are referring to the TextBoxes on your form. It only sees 3 local variables of type Integer which initialize to 0. This looks like VB6 code when default properties still existed.

Comment: The Val function is left over from VB6 and available for backward compatibility. It is replaced with .Net method .Parse, .TryParse(), CType(value, Type), CInt() or Convert.ToInt32 ()

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the front-end?

In short, your values (TextBox1, 2, 3) don't have any values because you haven't assigned them anything

```
Dim value1 as Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
Dim value2 as Integer = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
```

I'm assuming you have Textboxes on the front-end where you can input a number.  In the code-behind, you need use the .Text property to pull out the value from the textbox.  CInt is just a method to convert to an integer from string.

Also, I'd use the "AndAlso" logic instead of "And" -- it's just better on performance.  If the first set of logic fails, then it doesn't run the second part hence saving some performance time.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click

    Dim value1 As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim value2 As Integer = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
    Dim value3 As Integer = CInt(TextBox3.Text)

    If value1 < value2 AndAlso value1 < value3 Then
        MessageBox.Show(value1.ToString())
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Some output here....")
    End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .Min with an array to find the smallest value.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Declare an array of type Integer with 3 elements
    Dim value(2) As Integer
    'A variable to hold the parsed value of TextBoxes
    Dim intVal As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, intVal) Then
        'Assign the parsed value to an element of the array
        value(0) = intVal
    End If
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, intVal) Then
        value(1) = intVal
    End If
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, intVal) Then
        value(2) = intVal
    End If
    'Use .Min to get the smalles value
    Dim minNumber As Integer = value.Min
    MessageBox.Show($"The smalles value is {minNumber}")
    'Or
    'in older versions of vb.net
    'MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The smallest value is {0}", minNumber))
End Sub
```